# Create .htpasswd files within C#

Tags: c#, .htaccess, web, .htpasswd

For a small tool to automate website deployment I'd like to generate .htaccess and .htpasswd files.
How do I create the hashes for the passwords in my code?

Comment: Can you not use the existing "small tool" (htpasswd) that comes with Apache?

Comment: @Iridium: I tried this, thank you for the hint. It was a little bit uncomfortable. I used your approach with the SHA1 hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the documentation on the .htpasswd hashing methods [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html), the following should produce a suitable line of output that can be inserted into a .htpasswd file, using SHA1 as the hashing algorithm:

```
public static string CreateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
    {
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        return string.Format("{0}:{{SHA}}{1}", username, Convert.ToBase64String(hash));
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(CreateUser("TestUser", "TestPassword"));
```

Will output:

`TestUser:{SHA}YlBiWyJt9ihwriOvjT+sB2DXFYg=`

It should be straightforward to use this method to construct valid .htaccess files.